# how to create a primary key in a python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, counter

I looked at my ID in my dataframe and don't like it.  How can I create a dataframe in a python dataframe.

My thinking is a counter `sum 3*950` as ID. 
For example

```
    Primary ID

9*950   8550
9*951   8559
9*952   8568
9*953   8577
```

and so on

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

1. create a dataframe with values
2. set a specific column as index

Example (edited):

```py
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [9*950, 9*951, 9*952], 'year': [2012, 2014, 2013]})
    df = df.set_index('id')

    print(df)
```

output:

```
      year
id        
8550  2012
8559  2014
8568  2013
```

source : [panda documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

Comment: the line `df.set_index('id')` doesn't actually set the index.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed it now. you need to store it in df : `df = df.set_index('id')`